# How can i use ijson to extract a set of corresponding data from json file?

Tags: python, ijson

I have a json file just like this:

```
    {
  "CVE_data_type" : "CVE",
  "CVE_Items" : [ {
    "cve" : {

      "CVE_data_meta" : {
        "ID" : "CVE-2020-0001",
        "ASSIGNER" : "security@android.com"
      },
      ...
      
    "configurations" : {
      "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
      "nodes" : [ {
        "operator" : "OR",
        "children" : [ ],
        "cpe_match" : [ {
          "vulnerable" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:google:android:8.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
          "cpe_name" : [ ]
        }, {
          "vulnerable" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:google:android:8.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
          "cpe_name" : [ ]
        }]
      } ]
    },
   ...
    "publishedDate" : "2020-01-08T19:15Z",
    "lastModifiedDate" : "2020-01-14T21:52Z"
  }]
}
```

And i want to extract the CVE-ID and corresponding CPE,so i can lcoate the CVE-ID through CPE,here is my code

```
import ijson
import datetime


def parse_json(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as input_file:
        CVEID = ijson.items(input_file, 'CVE_Items.item.cve.CVE_data_meta.ID', )
        for id in CVEID:
            print("CVE id: %s" % id)
        # for prefix, event, value in parser:
        #     print('prefix={}, event={}, value={}'.format(prefix, event, value))

    with open(filename, 'rb') as input_file:
        cpes = ijson.items(input_file, 'CVE_Items.item.configurations.nodes.item.cpe_match.item', )
        for cpe in cpes:
            print("cpe: %s" % cpe['cpe23Uri'])


def main():
    
    parse_json("cve.json")
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results:

```
CVE id: CVE-2020-0633
CVE id: CVE-2020-0631
cpe: cpe:2.3:o:google:android:8.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe: cpe:2.3:o:google:android:10.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe: cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_10:1607:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe: cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_server_2016:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
```

But above this just extract the data and no correspondence.

Could anyone help? A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you need to keep track of CVE IDs and their corresponding CPEs you'll need to iterate over whole `cve` items and extract the bits of data you need (so you'll only do one pass through the file). Not as efficient memory-wise as your original iteration, but if each item in `CVE_Items` is not too big then it's not a problem:

```py
with open(filename, 'rb') as input_file:
    for cves in ijson.items(input_file, 'CVE_Items.item')
        cve_id = cve['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID']
        cpes = [match
                for node in cve['configurations']['nodes']
                for match in node['cpe_match']]
```

If you know there's always a single `cpe_match` element in `nodes` then you can replace the last list comprehension by `cve['configurations']['nodes'][0]['cpe_match']`

Comment: It works! I should iterate the TOP-level element. And yes,this is a big json file, my original iteration indeed unsmart.